# Which group user belongs (currently logged in)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Inside my view I check for user role using

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin");
```

and inside controller I'm using authorize attribute like

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, UserTwo")]
```

How can I check in controller which user (which group, Admin or Manager) is currently logged?

Comment: Create your own Authorize Attribute and implement Group also

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is still valid in the controller as `HttpContext` is available to you:

```
 HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin");
 HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("UserTwo");
```

If you're looking to figure out how to determine all the roles the user belongs to, it depends on how you are authenticating (ASP.Net Membership, Active Directory, etc...)